# How to remove gradient effect and drop shadow for UITabbaritem image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Hi i will like to remove the gradient effect and drop shadow for UITabbaritem image,

is it easy to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely you won't be able to do what you want. UITabbar uses custom drawing instead of subviews.